# Integrate pylint with github review comments

Tags: python, git, api, github, pylint

I am trying to make a script that runs pylint on the files present in the pull request and creates inline comments for the linting errors.

I got a hang on how to use [PyGithub](https://github.com/jacquev6/PyGithub). The problem is that in order to comment on a pull-request you will have to know the **commit** that modified the file and the **line number** from the patch. Full documentation on the review comments API is found [here](http://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/comments/).

Pylint returns the **line** in the resulted file. I need to get from foo/bar.py:30 to the commit that modified line 30 in foo/bar.py and to get the actual position in the **diff** for that file.

Is there something that already can do this or do I have to manually search for @@ lines in every commit involved in a pull request?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ? I am looking for an answer too.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is exactly what the `blame` feature does.

The only API I could find was [this `restfulgit`](https://github.com/hulu/restfulgit#blame).

Based on blind text search [this here](https://github.com/hulu/restfulgit/blob/master/restfulgit/porcelain/retrieval.py#L105) looks like the function that implements getting `blame` info, if you understand how it uses the underlying git api then you can just copy that part instead of using the `restfulgit`